# Unable to revoke/delete Pass type certificate Apple developer portal

Tags: certificate, provisioning-profile, passbook, iphone-developer-program, wallet

I have created Pass Type ID certificate earlier. (As shown in the image below)

[image]

I want to delete it now, but I'm unable to delete/revoke this certificate as the Revoke button is greyed out now.
(As shown in the image below) 
[image]

Comment: i have same problem. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Hello,
> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Program Support. As discussed on our call, and on call with my colleague Ruth, we advised that Pass Type ID certificates cannot be revoked or deleted. If it is in fact something else you are looking to remove please let me know and I will look into it for you.

This is the response I got from apple support

Answer (score -1):

I think you do not have the admin rights;

You may check your role from here (https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people)

Comment: I'm unable to delete Pass Type Certificate even with Admin access.

Comment: @Shoaib did you have any other solution? because i have admin rights too

Comment: Even with the admin rights "Pass Type Certificates" can’t be deleted till now.

Comment: You can't revoke Developer ID or Pass Type ID certificates using your developer account. Instead, send a request to Apple at product-security@apple.com to revoke these types of certificates. However, if you revoke a Developer ID certificate, users can no longer install apps that have been signed with that certificate. : Apple